# stored functions mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need, through a function or procedure, to count how much the reader (to pass through the parameters of his idi if so it is possible) should the books. please help to do this.

table Form

```
Create table Form (
idForm int not null primary key auto_increment,
date_of_issue date not null,
return_date date ,
idBook int not null
idReader int not null);
```

Filling a table Form

```
Insert into Form (idForm, date_of_issue, return_date, idBook,idReader)
Values(1, "2018-11-11","2018-11-11",1,4);

Insert into Form (idForm, date_of_issue, return_date, idBook,idReader)
    Values(2, "2019-11-11","2019-11-11",2,4);
```

Comment: How much the reader....should the books? You'll need to clarify what you mean there.

Comment: Why do you need a function or procedure to count a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` also would do the trick.. This looks to be a homework or job interview question.